# Is Trinity Force a good option on AP Kennen?

Tags: league-of-legends

Just bought kennen and found that Sheen is very nice on him (forget about mana).

I got almost always Lich Bane but since he benefits from autoatacks for his W and Trinity offers AS + HP + Slow on autoattacks I feel like is a good option.

So again is TF recommended for AP Kennen? (I know there is a AD Kennen but I dont feel like doing so).

Comment: You only need to put "ggClassic" in the "About Me" section of your user profile, not in the questions themselves :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AP Kennen obviously benefits from anything that gives AP or reduces cooldowns. He also needs to have a fair amount of survivability in order to effectively utilize his ultimate (Zhonya's Hourglass is popular for exactly that reason). Sheen is strong on him given how often he fires off his skills; following up with the auto-attack provides that extra layer of burst damage.

Zeal (the second part of Trinity Force), however, gives him nothing at all except some move speed... which he gets through Lightning Rush anyway.

Phage is nice-ish for its health, but the extra attack damage and the on-hit slow effect aren't very helpful. This item is surpassed on him entirely by Ryeli's Crystal Scepter.

Once you build your Trinity Force, the Sheen effect gets stronger, but you're spending a lot of money for that benefit. Lich Bane has the advantage here because, as AP Kennen, your AP will be much higher than your AD *and* you get the advantage of suddenly doing truckloads of AD from Lich Bane procs.

In short: Don't bother with Trinity Force. Lich Bane is a superior upgrade of Sheen, especially with other items you should seriously consider (Rylei's and Zhonya's).

Comment: Thank you so much, I´ll keep it clean and add the SHg to the build :)

Comment: Kennen main here. I've never tried Trinity Force, but I can say it's not quite accurate that Zeal gives him nothing. The most important stat on that for Kennen is attack speed, which is one of the most important stats on Kennen in general, so he can get his stuns off. I always build an early attack speed item on Kennen personally, rather it be Nashor's or Blade of the Ruined King. Otherwise I feel too vulnerable in between empowered auto attacks and like I can harass less.

Answer (score 1):

building sheen on ap kennen requires you to be close ranged to the enemy champion kennens attack range is 575 being close to other champions how ever puts yourself in danger since ap kennen is very squishy you die easier,most of the time in team fights you will be lucky to get all your skills off at once without dieing or using zhonyas inconclussion you wont proc sheen very often.

Comment: Something to keep in mind... thank you, the CD for Sheen is 2 secs, so in the Ult time I can proc 3 times at least... mmmm really good point... will test

Answer (score 1):

you'll find that as the game progresses, Kennen is not much more than an AoE ult. The most effective thing you can do, is build to make that as game-changing as possible.

Items that supplement this are: Hourglass, Abyssal, Rylai, Void, Deathcap (not in that order though)

While in theory, Lich bane works? It is a really expensive item that you won't be benefiting from all too much.

Most players nowadays rush a Will of the Ancients, and then proceed into items that I've listed above depending on matchup.

Mess around and see what you like the most, but I would certainly avoid Trinity Force.

Comment: I´ll defenitelly will mess around with the items, even tried once RageBlade, but didn´t like the output. Thank you.

Comment: Rageblade doesn't exactly support an AP build, since you won't really be auto attacking too much. I would try sticking to the items above and see how you do :)

Comment: Yeah, didn´t like the RB. Good thing the test was in a Coop v AI :)

Comment: Not enough people realize the benefit of playing Coop vs AI. Hell, I'm an 1800 ELO player that has over 2 years of experience in this game, and I still mess around with coop games to test item synergy and test builds :)